# Release logs time

Tags: tfs-2015, ms-release-management

The TFS server has the time zone set to UTC+1 but if I check the logs of the releases I see that the entries are on a different time zone (UTC-1) resulting in a 2 hours difference.

This is very confusing for the developers because all the other time values (from release summary) are on correct time zone.

How can I change the time zone of the release logs?

[image]
[image]

Comment: what time zone is the tfs server set to?

Comment: All servers(application tier, database tier, build/release agents) are set to UTC+1

Comment: Could you double check your time zone? It seems the time zone in the log would be UTC time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time zone in log is UTC time. And start time is based on the time zone set in TFS server

Comment: Is there a way to change this time zone of the logs?

Comment: I am afraid, there is no way to change the log timezone. Its design is based on w3c extended log file format. Which state that date and time should be in GMT. It is helpful in troubleshooting.